# Jquery date format

Tags: jquery

I want to validate my date field in "mm-dd-yyyy" format using jquery validation plugin. 
I want to display message "Please enter date in mm-dd-yyyy" if anybody vilates the date formar How will i do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Good idea! If you have a problem, let us know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the [dateISO](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/dateISO) validation method should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

in your js, after including validator

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("datetime", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}( \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})?$/.test(value);
    }, "Please enter a valid date (YYYY-MM-DD)"
);

// connect it to a css class
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
    datetime : { datetime : true }    
});
```

in your html

```
<input type='text' class='datetime' />
```

this actually allows to enter a datetime format for mysql (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS), but whatever.

$2c,
*-pike